# Running MPMediaQuery in GCD

Tags: objective-c, ios7, grand-central-dispatch, mpmediaquery

The following code runs great and gives me the results I am looking for. However, I would like to run it in its own thread. Is MPMediaQuery thread safe, and what am I doing wrong, if it is?

```
-(NSArray*) mediaItemsFromPersistentIds:(NSArray*) mediaPersistentIds
{
    if (debug==1) {
        NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }

       MPMediaQuery *mediaQuery = [MPMediaQuery new];
       NSArray *itemsmediaQuery = mediaQuery.items;
       NSPredicate *predicate   = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", @"itemId", mediaPersistentIds];

    return [itemsmediaQuery filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

When I try the following, I get

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MPMediaItemCollectionInitException', reason: 'items array must not be empty'

I know the `[itemsmediaQuery filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]` is being returned as (null)

```
-(NSArray*) mediaItemsFromPersistentIds:(NSArray*) mediaPersistentIds
{
    if (debug==1) {
        NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }
    __block NSArray *itemsmediaQuery;
    __block NSPredicate *predicate;

    dispatch_queue_t mediaQueryQueue = dispatch_queue_create("media query", NULL);
    dispatch_async(mediaQueryQueue, ^{

        MPMediaQuery *mediaQuery      = [MPMediaQuery new];
        itemsmediaQuery = mediaQuery.items;
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", @"itemId", mediaPersistentIds];

    });

    return [itemsmediaQuery filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to request these items in the background.

Right now, you're not actually running the query in the background. You could do something like this:

```c
- (void)mediaItemsFromPersistentIds:(NSArray*)ids
                           callback:(void (^)(NSArray *items))callback {
    dispatch_queue_t mediaQueryQueue = dispatch_queue_create("media query", NULL);
    dispatch_async(mediaQueryQueue, ^{
        MPMediaQuery *mediaQuery = [MPMediaQuery new];
        itemsmediaQuery = mediaQuery.items;
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", @"itemId", ids];

        // Do the query
        NSArray *items = [itemsmediaQuery filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        // Post the query results to the main thread in some way
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // You could pass this off to a delegate or callback block
            if (callback)
                callback(items);
        });
    });
}
```

And to call it:

```c
NSArray *ids = ...
[someObj mediaItemsFromPersistentIds:ids callback:^(NSArray *items) {
    // Do something with `items`
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How do I return the NSArray *items, like in my example above?  This method returns an NSArray.  Thanks again for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Added some more detail

Comment: I implemented the following:      `NSArray *ids = [self mediaItemsFromPersistentIds:collection callback:^(NSArray *items) {
        MPMediaItemCollection *mediaCollection = [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:items];
        [_musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:mediaCollection];
    }];` and get the following error: Initializing 'NSArray *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'  I resolved this by removing the `NSArray *ids = ` Seems to work great now.  Thanks for the help.